# How to fix " Error: Permission denied @ [file directory here]" while 'limking' python 3 on Mac

Tags: python

When I tried to install Python 3 on my Mac, something went wrong. So I tried to do it again, and it turns out that it installed correctly, but is not "linked."

I got:

"Warning: python 3.7.1 is already installed, it's just not linked"

But then when I tried to link it, I got:

" Error: Permission denied @ [file directory here]"

Comment: don't know how you installed your python, personally, I recommend using `pyenv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this one:**

```
    sudo mkdir /usr/local/Frameworks
    sudo chown $(whoami):admin /usr/local/Frameworks
```

**Note:** file patch depends on your folder stucture